# Click Not Firing on Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html button that is hooked up to a JQuery function at the top of my page, but the click does not seem to be firing? Is there something I'm missing?

```
$(function(){
                $('#ctl00_content_hidePast').click(function() {
                    var dt = new Date($.now() - 30 * 60000);
                    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
                    $("td.bgtime").each(function() {
                        var bookingTime = ($(this).text().split(':'));
                        var d = new Date();
                        d.setHours(+bookingTime[0]);
                        d.setMinutes(bookingTime[1]);

                        var state = $("#ctl00_content_hdnPastBookingToggle").val();

                        if ($(d) > time) {
                            var timeRow = $(this).parent();
                            $(timeRow).toggle("slow",
                                function() {
                                    if (state.val === "0") {
                                        state.val = "1";} 
                                    else if (state.val === "1") {
                                        state.val = "0";
                                    };
                                });
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
```

And the button:

```
<button id="ctl00_content_hidePast"><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i> Hide/Show Past Bookings</button>
```

Comment: is it a dynamic button?

Comment: are you sure from the id? can you show the html

Comment: Do you get any error on console?

Comment: What's with this strange condition `if ($(d) > time)` and `state.val === "..."` where `state` is a string ?

Comment: No errors on the console

Comment: If your button is in a `form`the default behavior is to submit the form. Since you're not using `preventDefault` the form will be submitted. If that is the case, use `type="button"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(function(){
                $(document).on('click','#ctl00_content_hidePast', function() {
                    var dt = new Date($.now() - 30 * 60000);
                    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
                    $("td.bgtime").each(function() {
                        var bookingTime = ($(this).text().split(':'));
                        var d = new Date();
                        d.setHours(+bookingTime[0]);
                        d.setMinutes(bookingTime[1]);

                        var state = $("#ctl00_content_hdnPastBookingToggle").val();

                        if ($(d) > time) {
                            var timeRow = $(this).parent();
                            $(timeRow).toggle("slow",
                                function() {
                                    if (state.val === "0") {
                                        state.val = "1";} 
                                    else if (state.val === "1") {
                                        state.val = "0";
                                    };
                                });
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
```

In this case you bind the event to the document. This is usually used when you have dynamic dom elements. You don't need to bind the click event to the document. Actually it's recommended to attach it to non dynamic parent. For example the div that will contain the buttons. In that case the code would be:

```
  $(document).on('click','div that contains the buttons selector', function() ..
```

It just makes things lighter. But since I don't have the dom structure I gave you an answer that will work in any case.

Comment: Please explain what you did.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a dynamic button you have to use the following:

```
$(function(){
                $('#ctl00_content_hidePast').on("click", function() {
                    var dt = new Date($.now() - 30 * 60000);
                    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
                    $("td.bgtime").each(function() {
                        var bookingTime = ($(this).text().split(':'));
                        var d = new Date();
                        d.setHours(+bookingTime[0]);
                        d.setMinutes(bookingTime[1]);

                        var state = $("#ctl00_content_hdnPastBookingToggle").val();

                        if ($(d) > time) {
                            var timeRow = $(this).parent();
                            $(timeRow).toggle("slow",
                                function() {
                                    if (state.val === "0") {
                                        state.val = "1";} 
                                    else if (state.val === "1") {
                                        state.val = "0";
                                    };
                                });
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
```

or (Deprecated)

```
$(function(){
                $('#ctl00_content_hidePast').live("click", function() {
                    var dt = new Date($.now() - 30 * 60000);
                    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
                    $("td.bgtime").each(function() {
                        var bookingTime = ($(this).text().split(':'));
                        var d = new Date();
                        d.setHours(+bookingTime[0]);
                        d.setMinutes(bookingTime[1]);

                        var state = $("#ctl00_content_hdnPastBookingToggle").val();

                        if ($(d) > time) {
                            var timeRow = $(this).parent();
                            $(timeRow).toggle("slow",
                                function() {
                                    if (state.val === "0") {
                                        state.val = "1";} 
                                    else if (state.val === "1") {
                                        state.val = "0";
                                    };
                                });
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: live is deprecated for a loong time, .on() will not work too (that way) if it's dynamically added, correct answer is the other one ;)

Comment: `on()` will work here. click only matches on elements whch are available on load. Because click is javascript event and will be set before `.load()`

Comment: Nope. If that is a dynamically added button, `on` will work on this way: `$(document).on('click', '#ctl00_content_hidePast', function() {//...});`

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#ctl00_content_hidePast', function() {//...}); was the one that worked in the end